# Can I use recessed downlight with GU24 base socket using adapter?

Tags: ceiling, recessed-lighting, fire-hazard

All ceiling lights in my home have GU24 base socket. I recently saw "recessed downlight" in Costco.  It has E26 base type and is 9.4 watts. I googled and could not find similar light with GU24 base. However I found "GU24 Base Socket to LED Recessed Lighting" ( some no-name brand in Amazon ). Can I safely use those adapters or is there any safety hazard.

Just in case, I saw this question and thought if my situation is similar ( but in my case bulb is 9.4 watts! ): [GU24 to E26 light socket adapter -- any risks?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171748/gu24-to-e26-light-socket-adapter-any-risks)

[image: Recessed downlight]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GU24 socket is designed to stop people from installing inefficient incandescent bulbs in place of efficient CFLs or LED bulbs. Of course this means that finding a high quality adapter from GU24 to E26 is difficult, by design. That isn't what you are doing, though. You're staying within the spirit of Title 24 by putting in these LED retrofits. I see two paths forward.

1. Follow the plan you propose. You aren't likely to be able to get UL listed GU24 to downlight conversion kit adapters. However the power levels involved are low, and as mentioned you are staying within the spirit of the rule. Is this ideal? No. However it is not the worst idea around.
2. Retrofit with GU24 Title 24 compliant downlight conversion kits. Cree makes these. Other manufacturers may make them as well. This will be the code compliant and safest approach.

Only you know how close to the rules you want to stay. Personally I would probably do the second, but if I could only source the parts to do the first I wouldn't lose sleep over it.

Answer (score 2):

The risk is that the adapter is almost certainly not UL or ETL listed. As a result you have no guarantee that it is designed and built properly to handle 120V at even 9W. If it is built properly then yes a 9W bulb will be perfectly safe in terms of heat. But it is a risk.

The options are:

- find compatible bulbs that meet your requirements
- replace the fixture with one that uses Edison base bulbs
- replace the fixture with one that has integral LEDs

In all options, stick with UL or ETL listed stuff. In the last case, look for a name brand and a long warranty as you don't want to have to replace in a year or two.

Comment: I think OP is proposing using the UL listed downlight adapters in their picture with a GU24 to those orange downlight connectors that most of us don't know the name of. Given that they are only handling a couple dozen mA of current it's a lower risk application than a lot of the other questions we get here. Personally I would still prefer to use listed hardware, since it's available.

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to post the amazon link of GU24 adapter I am talking about.  It is some no name brand  ( Says:  brand: TWDRTDD )